# Prime number written as a sum

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a question related to prime numbers which has been tough for me to get forward with. I wonder whether every prime number can be written as the sum of two numbers such that the product of the two numbers yields another number which can be factored into an additional two pairs whose sum happens to differ by plus or minus $1$ from the original pair.

In other words, is following true:

> For every prime $p$ there exist positive integers $a,b,c,d$ satisfying $ab=cd$ such that $p=a+b$ and $c+d=p\pm1$.

So for example $7= 4+3$ and $3\cdot4=12$. Then $12$ can be factored as $6\cdot2$ and $6+2 =8$ which differs by $1$ from the $4+3$. I have checked for most primes but is this trivial ? If not is there a standard method to start with trying to prove this? I am sorry for not using math format but just curious to get some feedback.  Thank you

Comment: "i have checked for most primes" --- that must have taken a while!

Comment: "If $p$ is prime then there exists integers $a,b$ such that $$p=a+b \text{ and } ab=n \text{ and } \frac{n}{n_1} + \frac{n}{n_2} = (a+b) \pm 1$$ where $n=n_1 n_2$." Please ensure that this is indeed the statement you wish to prove.

Comment: Sorry just meant to ensure I didn't just check for the first few primes in fact why even apologize? Andrew Tawfeek yes that is correct

Comment: John Hughes yes it took 48 hours on a laptop to check primes up to 1 million

Comment: Updated the question so it is more clear what is asking, please correct if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: The statement is true for every prime $p\ge 5$ (See my answer), but not for $p\le 3$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p\equiv 2\mod 3$, then the choice $$a=\frac{2p+2}{3}$$ $$b=\frac{p-2}{3}$$ $$c=\frac{p+1}{3}$$ $$d=\frac{2p-4}{3}$$ does the job ; we have $ab=cd$ and $a+b=c+d+1$. In the case $p\equiv 1\mod 3$, choose $$a=\frac{2p-2}{3}$$ $$b=\frac{p+2}{3}$$ $$c=\frac{p-1}{3}$$ $$d=\frac{2p+4}{3}$$ Then, we have $ab=cd$ and $a+b=c+d-1$

Comment: That's a great answer thank you Peter

Comment: This shows that there must be one solution so my next quest is how do we know whether or not there is a solution of a number is congruent 0 mod 3

Comment: @argamon Seems for $p\equiv 0\mod 3$, there are infinite many counterexamples.

Comment: Yes I wonder then whether there are conditions when it works and when it doesn't. Also there are other solutions in addition to your answer I wonder what makes those work? For instance 13 has two pairs a,b

Comment: @argamon With Wolfram alpha I found out a criterion allowing to find the solutions (if there are one). A pair $(a,b)$ satisfies (with suitable $c$ and $d$) the system $ab=cd , a+b=c+d-1$ if and only if $a^2-2a(b-1)+(b+1)^2$ is a perfect square and the system $ab=cd , a+b=c+d+1$ if and only if $a^2-2a(b+1)+(b-1)^2$ is a perfect square. That might help. For $n=13$, there is a pair in both variants.

Comment: @argamon The final criterion is very interesting indeed : for $p\ge 2$, a solution of the desired form exists if and only if $2p\pm1$ is not a twin-prime-pair. Since it is conjectured that there are infinite many twin-prime-pairs, we probably have infinite many unsolvable cases.

Comment: Hmm wow how did you figure that out?

Comment: I replaced $b$ by $n-a$ and again with Wolfram Alpha I found an expression that could be written as $m^2+2n+1=p^2$ or $m^2-2n+1=p^2$ (Depending on the variant). For each solution of those equations $m$ and $n$ have equal parity (which can be easily checked by analyzing the equation modulo $4$). If we have such an $m$, we get a pair $(a/b)$ using $\frac{n\pm m}{2}$, which is a non-trivial solution, if $m<n$.

Comment: Now, if $2n+1$ or $2n-1$ is not prime, the equation $(p-m)(p+m)=2n+1$ or $(m-p)(m+p)=2n-1$ has a non-trivial solution leading to the desired $m$. Using my criterion above ($a^2-2a\cdots$) , I finally checked upto $10^4$ the criterion, so it should be correct.

Comment: Very interesting do you think there is anything more that could be learned or looked at here?

Comment: @argamon Perhaps to find out how many solutions exist , this should depend on the number of non-trivial factorizations of $2n-1$ and $2n+1$.

Comment: Ok great thank you Peter are you a professor by the way?

Comment: @argamon Unfortunately no.

Comment: Haha you should be

Comment: so when you say to find how many solutions what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Peter if we showed that there are infinitely many non solvable cases then it implies infinitely many twin primes?

Comment: is that a thing to consider?

Comment: @argamon In fact a nice idea, but I would not be too optimistic. Nevertheless, it could be an interesting approach.

Comment: Haha ok thanks Peter one thing that mivht be intersting is that ive found other numbers like 144 and 180 where there are 3 consecutive pairs so like a,b   =c+d-1=e+f-2 and ab=cd=ef

Comment: @argamon Great, perhaps this can be generalized.

Comment: is there any way we can figure out how to find the case for 3 consecutive pairs like for 144  we have  (12,12) (9,16) (8,18) like can wolfram figure out that too?

Comment: the above comment was for you